# Filter options with conditions JS / VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter

I would like this filter to work, for option "pattern" field description should have params [ok] && field process should have params [pattern].
For option "fast" field description should have params [ok] && field process should have params [].
The problem is that the filter is not working when for option "fast" when field description should have params [ok] && field process should have params []. Dont know if the problem is the empty array.

```
filterConfig() {
      return [
        {
          name: "description",
          field: "description",
          type: "term",
          label: "description",
          options: [
            { label: "pattern", value: "true" },
            { label: "fast", value: "false" },
          ],
          onBeforeLoad(filters, filter) {
            const memo = filters.filter((f) => f.field !== "description");

            if (filter?.params?.length !== 1) return memo;

            if (filter?.params?.includes("true")) {
              memo.push({
                type: "term",
                field: "description",
                params: ["OK"],
              });
              memo.push({
                type: "term",
                field: "process",
                params: ["pattern"],
              });
            }

            if (filter?.params?.includes("false")) {
              memo.push({
                type: "term",
                field: "description",
                params: ["OK"],
              });
              memo.push({
                type: "term",
                field: "process",
                params: [],
              });
            }

            return memo;
          },
        },
      ];
    },
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: The problem is that the filter is not working when for option "fast" when field description should have params [ok] && field process should have params []. Dont know if the problem is the empty array.

Comment: you need to write that into your question otherwise nobody knows what your problem is ...